# Why I can't correctly append a tag having the id specified? Is it a character escaping problems?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-append

I am pretty new in JavaScript and Jquery and I have the following problem that I think could be related to some character escaping.

So I have this simple JQuery script:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      //alert(exludeUserAgent());
      if(exludeUserAgent()) {
          //$( "#sezioneBenvenuto" ).remove();
          //$( "#sezioneLogo" ).remove();
          $( "#sezioneLogin" ).remove();

          $( ".container" ).append( "<section id="sezioneErrore"><p>TEST</p></section>" );
      }
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that when the **append** statment is performed it give me the following error:

```
**SCRIPT1006: Previsto ')'**
```

on this line:

```
$( ".container" ).append( "<section id="sezioneErrore"><p>TEST</p>
```

If I remove the **id="sezioneErrore"** and I append a section tag without the id definition I have no problem.

Why? What am I missing? The problem could be the " character of the **id="sezioneErrore"** ? If yes how can I try to escape it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string is breaking as you've used double quote that is causing the syntax error.

To solve this error, you can either

1. Use **double quote inside single quote**(and vice versa)
2. **Escape the quotes inside the string**

**Examples:**

Use single quotes outside

```
$(".container").append('<section id="sezioneErrore"><p>TEST</p></section>');
```

Or single quotes inside double quotes

```
$(".container").append("<section id='sezioneErrore'><p>TEST</p></section>");
```

If you want to use double quotes inside double quote, escape it

```
$(".container").append("<section id=\"sezioneErrore\"><p>TEST</p></section>");
```

Same for single quotes

```
$(".container").append('<section id=\'sezioneErrore\'><p>TEST</p></section>');
```